# Two prices on one product. Cant find info how

Tags: price, currency, convert, magento-1.9

i have a different request my price should look like.Its only because my country is currently in currency changing period. So i need to price look like this [image]

It doesn't matter in what currency but i thin u get the idea. price  should apear everywhere  like this   500US/300EU  . This is just for information . Completed order bill will be formed in bank page form. But its the law requested to show 2 prices .

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$exchangeRate=(the rate of exchange between currencies);
$price=$product->getPrice();
$differentPrice=$product*$exchangeRate;
$formatedPrice= $price . '/' . $differentPrice;
?>
<span><?php echo $formatedPrice ?></span>
```

something like that should work.

Alternatively you can create a separate price attribute in admin for your products which will have the new price within it.  However, I feel this option will be a bit labor intensive depending upon how many products you have.  The code would be quite similar to what is above but instead of the exchange rate business you'd just have two getFunction() calls.

Comment: Im sorry i forgot to tell that im a total niewbie in this stuff. Where should i put this code?

Comment: try some place like .../template/catalog/product/price.phtml

Comment: doesnt work gives error.

Comment: what does that error say?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getPrice() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml on line 474

Comment: In that page the product is usually initialized something like this: $product = $this->getProduct();  Find out where in your phtml file the product is initialized and use that product.  I can't really do this entire thing for you.